# Записать имя папки в переменную в bat через команду dir

Tags: cmd, bat

У меня в папке есть подпапка, всегда одна и всегда с разным названием. Грубо говоря может быть `C:\test\01` или `C:\test\ab`
В батнике я прописываю команду `dir`, но как теперь название подпапки обернуть в переменную?, чтобы дальше с ней работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %x in ('dir /b /a:D C:\test\') do set mypath=C:\test\%x
```

Comment: только может быть %%x ? вопрошающий же говорил про `.bat` файл

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Ну я не верю, что товарищ не в курсе подобных мелочей...

Comment: Я больше беспокоюсь за тех, кто потом найдет этот ответ через поиск

Answer (score 0):

Ну если папка всегда одна, то в переменную можно имя папки положить следующим образом

```
for /f %d in ('dir /B /A:D %CD%') do set "nameDir=%~d"
```

Это при условии, что вы находитесь в той же папке. Иначе можно так

```
set "workDir=Путь_к_папке"
for /f %d in ('dir /B /A:D %workDir%') do set "nameDir=%~d"
```

Использовать через

```
%nameDir%
```